# Docker env variables configuration

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
    config:
        image: my-spring-boot-java-app
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=native
          - LOGSTASH_TCP_IP=192.168.0.65
          - LOGSTASH_TCP_PORT=5000
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8001:8001
```

In my logback.xml I have this:

```
<appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>${logstash.tcp.ip}:${logstash.tcp.port}</destination>

...

</appender>
```

When I run docker build I get an error due to the fact that the destination (logstash) is not reachable.

Can you help me to understand the cause of this mistake?

Comment: You are running docker... I doubt that logstash is actually running on localhost in your container.

Comment: logstash is running

Comment: I nowhere said that logstash isn't running.. I highly doubt that logstash is running inside the **same docker container**. You are inside your container NOT on your local machine.

Comment: ok ok, logstash is running in docker container in an another machine

Comment: ${logstash.tcp.ip} keep it inside double quote:
"${logstash.tcp.ip}"

Comment: So it isn't on `localhost` then... So then how should it connect...

Comment: Sorry localhost is a mistake, I have updated the post

Comment: Have you tried to configure the network_mode? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode